# ZXing Colorido .net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, framework, qrcode

Preciso criar um qrcode colorido usando o zxing.net porem não consigo e não acho nem 1 tutorial na internet mesmo pesquisando e tentando a dias, alguém tem alguma ideia de como faço pra desenvolver 1 qrcode colorido usando zxing e c#/.net. Se ajuda aqui esta meu codigo de gerar o qrcode.

CODIGO:

```
public static class QRHelper
{

    public static IHtmlString GenerateQrCode(this HtmlHelper html, string url)
    {
        int QRCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 496;
        int QRCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH = 496;
        var qrWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
        qrWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;
        var BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        var ModuleColor = Color.Green;

        qrWriter.Options = new EncodingOptions() { Height = QRCODE_IMAGE_HEIGHT, Width = QRCODE_IMAGE_WIDTH };
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var q = qrWriter.Write(url);
        q.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        var img = new TagBuilder("img");
        string alt = "QR code";
        img.Attributes.Add("src", String.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())));
        img.Attributes.Add("alt", alt);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(img.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));

    }

}
```

Comment: Qual é a versão da biblioteca?

Comment: estou usando a versão 0.16.2.